# create a record with dynamically Model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose the models' name are `User, Order, Item`

How to do

`User.create, Order.create, Item.create` dynamically within a loop ?

Ex.

```
    ["User", "Order", "Item"].each do |MODEL|
        MODEL.create
    end
```

Comment: you just want to create models randomly on fly or there are more conditions to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/Inflector/constantize)

```
["User", "Order", "Item"].each do |model|
    model.classify.constantize.create(.......)
end
```

`Object.const_get` is ruby method, the answer from August

Well, `constantize` is ror method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.const_get` ([documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get)):

```
["User", "Order", "Item"].each do |model|
  Object.const_get(model).create
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array of strings why not just use the classes themselves?

```
[User, Order, Item].each do |klass|
  klass.create
end
```